# tvOS: How to track down: Invalid Executable - The executable 'xy' does not contain bitcode

Tags: xcode, llvm, tvos, bitcode

My `tvOS` app repeatedly failed on server-side validation by Apple with email notification saying:

> Invalid Executable - The executable 'VPK_FULL_TV.app/VPK_FULL_TV' does
>   not contain bitcode

I've used the method described here: [How to check if a framework is BITCODE supported for Xcode7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808642/how-to-check-if-a-framework-is-bitcode-supported-for-xcode7)
and all my libs/frameworks print out at least one line with `segname __LLVM`.

1. I wonder, how sufficient is this test with `otool`? Could it happen that the test prints out the line `segname __LLVM` but some function is still left out without the bitcode?
2. is there another way of testing the bitcode completeness?
3. I also tried this test on std libs e.g. `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/usr/lib/libresolv.9.tbd` but that prints NO `segname __LLVM` line thus showing that there is no bitcode included. I should be, right? What is this .tbd lib anyway?

BTW, here are some shortcuts for running the `otool` if you find it useful:

```
find . -name '*a' -type f -exec ./test_bitcode.sh {} \;
```

**test_bitcode.sh**

```
echo ""
echo "***** TESTING $1"
otool -l $1 | grep __LLVM | head -n1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your libraries are not being `strip -x` post being built with bitcode.

I found strip removes the bitcode from the libraries

Also kinda like your script:
**Bitcode Checking Script:**

https://github.com/danoli3/Bitcode-Check-Script

**Usage:** `bitcodeCheck "boost_system.a"`

**Results:**

```
------------------
BITCODE=YES for: boost_system.a
------------------
```

It uses the basis of `otool` and `__LLVM` as specified by **Apple**