# How to check a framework contains full bitcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, bitcode

From Xcode7, any framework built with your app should have bitcode if you want to enable bitcode support for your app. 
I'd like to know a way to check whether a framework project has bitcode or not. 
There is a similar question here ([How to check if a framework is BITCODE supported for Xcode7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32808642/1709287)), but the answers there are about checking bitcode of static libary file of .a or .o extention.

I want to check the existence of bitcode inside .framework package, and have been wondering there should be a way to check it on .swiftmodule files inside a .framework package.

(One of the reasons I want to know is that I'm trying to support bitcode in my own framework project, but have never succeeded in doing so since I got missing-bitcode error when I exported my framework package to an app project and built the app. I thought it's nice to have a tool to check it directly rather than knowing it after embedding it to an app project and building the app.)

Comment: you mean [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode)?

Comment: @cat Check the link below about Bitcode 

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
otool -l binary_name | grep __bitcode
```

you will see one or more `segname __bitcode` entries if it does have bitcode or empty output if does not.

Comment: I tried, and there was nothing returned. Does this mean there is no bitcode in the binary ?

Comment: @TakamitsuMizutori yes.

Comment: I think this is not a fool proof method - running it on a library showed me results, but using `ebcutil` shows that the bitcode has markers only and is not the full bitcode.