# How to use otool to check if bitcode is enabled

Tags: xcode, xcode8, bitcode, otool

I am playing around with otool now for hour, but I didn't figure out how to get infos, if a binary is bitcode enabled.

It tried the following:

First I build a simple iOS app and run:

```
otool -arch arm64 -l testApp1 | grep bitcode
```

After that I downloaded a binary framework from [kontakt.io](https://github.com/kontaktio/kontakt-ios-sdk/releases/download/v1.2.2/KontaktSDK.framework.zip). I am sure that there bitcode is enabled. So I tried:

```
otool -arch arm64 -l KontaktSDK | grep bitcode
```

I also got no infos back. Do I something wrong? Is this a bug with the new Xcode8?

The reason why I play around with this is, that I have build a binary framework and I don't know why sometimes the framework is fully bitcode enabled and sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33105733/981049) there's two possible things to check, `bitcode` and `__LLVM`.

When I download the KontaktSDK, I can do this:

```
[.../KontaktSDK.framework]:;otool -arch arm64 -l KontaktSDK | grep __LLVM
  segname __LLVM
   segname __LLVM
```

Comment: Does it mean, that __LLVM is found, bitcode is enabled?

Comment: that appears to be the case (looking at many other StackOverflow & Google hits here), but I haven't found the definitive documentation on apple.com.