# Bitcode not being included in my Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, bitcode

I'm trying to build a Framework with bitcode included. To do so I've used [this post](https://medium.com/@heitorburger/static-libraries-frameworks-and-bitcode-6d8f784478a9) (the section about universal libraries).

After that I've tried to check that the bitcode is actually included in the result following
 [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755775/how-to-check-a-static-library-is-built-contain-bitcode) but it seems more difficult to do it with a framework. So, I've done it with my .a (which I also generate), and the result is that the library does include the bitcode.

The problem comes when I try to use it in an app with "Enable Bitcode" set to "Yes", it gives me the error:

> bitcode bundle could not be generated because 'path/to/my/lib' was
>   built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode
>   must be generated...

What could I be missing? Should I change something in the app, or could it be necessary to make an additional configuration in the Framework project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey finally I found the solution. In my case I had some library imported in my project which didn't have bitcode added.

You have to check that every library you use has bitcode and, if not, update to a version that has it (or download the code and compile it yourself with bitcode enabled as I've done).

You can check if a lib has bitcode enabled with the link in my question, but I'll paste it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755775/how-to-check-a-static-library-is-built-contain-bitcode/33105733#33105733) again.

Hope this help somebody.