# Xcode: bitcode not included when doing Single-object Prelink

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

I'm using Xcode to prelink a collection of object files (`*.o`) and static libraries (`*.a`), all containing bitcode, into  a single static library using Single-Object Prelinking.

In doing so, the resulting prelinked file does not contain bitcode.

The prelinking command and options emitted by Xcode looks like this:

```
ld -r -arch arm64 -bitcode_bundle -bitcode_verify -syslibroot
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.6.sdk 
a.o 
b.o 
...
x.a
y.a
-o libABC-arm64-master.o
```

The documentation for the `bitcode_bundle` option indicates that it "requires all the object files, static libraries and user frameworks/dylibs contain bit-code". I have used `otool` to verify that all of the constituent files contain bitcode.

No errors are raised or logged the by the `ld` command, even when I test it directly from the command line, separately from Xcode.

I'm stumped. And any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

***Update:*** In further testing, I can create a prelinked file containing only any single `.o` file, and the final prelinked file WILL contain bitcode. However, including any two of those `.o` files, each of which contains bitcode, causes the prelinked file to contain NO bitcode.

Comment: Have you tried the same process on slim objects with only a single arch? I remember Apple had a stance of not supporting fat libs at all some time ago.

Comment: @Kikaxa Good suggestion. The latest code now generates single-arch files (actually XCFramework components), but the result is the same. The single-object prelink stage still seems to be interfering with bitcode. I'll edited the original question to remove references to fat files.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should check for _LLVM section in the result library, not _bitcode:

```
otool -l lib.a | grep _LLVM
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33105733/13891048

Comment: Thanks. You are correct in that if I remove bitcode generation, there is no `__LLVM` section. Strange that on files that are _not_ prelinked, there are both `bitcode` and `__LLVM` sections.